# Обработка папок с ресурсами в контроллере

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, как сделать чтобы контроллер и з паки подхватывал автоматом представление из папки?

Писать в контроллере

```
return PartialView("~/Views/HtmlHelpers/TopSide/Index.cshtml", ....
```

Совсем не классно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контроллер и так подхватывает автоматически, если соблюдать вложенность папок...
Есть контроллер **Home**, при обращении к методу в этом контроллере например **Index**, **View** будет искаться по адресу **~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

На твоем примере вложенность нарушена **~/Views/HtmlHelpers/TopSide/Index.cshtml**, т.е. если **TopSide** это контроллер, то папка **HtmlHelpers** лишняя... 
Ты рендеришь **PartialView**, у них свои правила для названия **"_[MethodName]Partial.cshtml"**
т.е. называться он должен **_IndexPartial.cshtml**. Если ты хочешь нарушить вложенность, то придется указывать... **return PartialView("~/Views/HtmlHelpers/TopSide/Index.cshtml"**

*Обновление*

Забыл добавить, не корректно называть папку в видах HtmlHelpers, по скольку это специальный функционал http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs и обычно такая папка есть в корне проекта, где находятся cs классы

Comment: Забыл добавить, не корректно называть папку в видах HtmlHelpers, по скольку это специальный функционал http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs и обычно такая папка есть в корне проекта, где находятся cs классы